# How to solve "Bitmap is not valid" error when I fetch image from online

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory, color-palette, android-palette

I am trying to make an app which shows images from online database. but I want to use palette API to get vibrant color from each image. But I think I don't know how to use Bitmap decodeResource method OR Palette. please guide me how to use Bitmap factory.decoderResource with Palette in online URL or URI image file.

here is the method which I used in activity class recylceview subclass error shows in line number 171 "Bitmap is not valid":

```
170    Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mCursor.getPosition());
171    Palette.generateAsync(photo, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    int bgColor = palette.getLightVibrantColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    holder.placeNameHolder.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
                }
            });
```

So here is the error:

```
10-29 17:39:42.067 31692-31750/com.example.xyzreader E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
10-29 17:39:42.282 31692-31692/com.example.xyzreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.xyzreader, PID: 31692
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bitmap is not valid
                                                                           at android.support.v7.graphics.Palette$Builder.<init>(Palette.java:616)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.from(Palette.java:100)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.generateAsync(Palette.java:134)
                                                                           at com.example.xyzreader.ui.ArticleListActivity$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(ArticleListActivity.java:171)
                                                                           at com.example.xyzreader.ui.ArticleListActivity$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(ArticleListActivity.java:125)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6062)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6095)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5277)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1568)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:678)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:600)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1142)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:836)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:850)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17519)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
10-29 17:39:42.282 31692-31692/com.example.xyzreader E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

1- ArticleListActivity.class:

```
public class ArticleListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_list);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout)).setTitle("XYZ Reader");

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            refresh();
        }

        //1---- I added setOnRefreshListener and then call refresh method in onRefresh()
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               refresh();
            }
        });
    }

    private void refresh() {
        startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(mRefreshingReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(UpdaterService.BROADCAST_ACTION_STATE_CHANGE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mRefreshingReceiver);
    }

    private boolean mIsRefreshing = false;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRefreshingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (UpdaterService.BROADCAST_ACTION_STATE_CHANGE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                mIsRefreshing = intent.getBooleanExtra(UpdaterService.EXTRA_REFRESHING, false);
                updateRefreshingUI();
            }
        }
    };

    private void updateRefreshingUI() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(mIsRefreshing);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return ArticleLoader.newAllArticlesInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(cursor);
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_column_count);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm =
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(sglm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    }

    private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        private Cursor mCursor;

        public Adapter(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            return mCursor.getLong(ArticleLoader.Query._ID);
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            ItemsContract.Items.buildItemUri(getItemId(vh.getAdapterPosition()))));
                }
            });
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            holder.titleView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TITLE));
            holder.subtitleView.setText(
                    DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                            mCursor.getLong(ArticleLoader.Query.PUBLISHED_DATE),
                            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS,
                            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString()
                            + " by "
                            + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AUTHOR));
            holder.thumbnailView.setImageUrl(
                    mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.THUMB_URL),
                    ImageLoaderHelper.getInstance(ArticleListActivity.this).getImageLoader());
            holder.thumbnailView.setAspectRatio(mCursor.getFloat(ArticleLoader.Query.ASPECT_RATIO));



            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mCursor.getPosition());
            Palette.generateAsync(photo, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    int bgColor = palette.getLightVibrantColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                    holder.placeNameHolder.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout placeNameHolder;
        public DynamicHeightNetworkImageView thumbnailView;
        public TextView titleView;
        public TextView subtitleView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            placeNameHolder=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.placeNameHolder);
            thumbnailView = (DynamicHeightNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
            subtitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_subtitle);
        }
    }
}
```

2- Xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:paddingTop="116dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry for late reply,

I forgotten to answer this question after solving problem. So here is the answer :
I found Picasso API for Palette color and here is the code of Picasso API with Palette feature

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.PHOTO_URL))
                    .into(Imagebar, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) Imagebar.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                Palette.from(bitmap)
                                        .generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                                                Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = palette.getDominantSwatch();
                                                if (vibrantSwatch != null) {
                                                    bylineView.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb());
                                                    bylineView.setTextColor(vibrantSwatch.getTitleTextColor());
                                                    coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getPopulation());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Error on image load.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
});
```